# Passing arguments through 'open' command to AppleScript

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

I have the following AppleScript saved as `.app`.

```
on run argv
    do shell script "echo " & (item 1 of argv) & " >> ~/Desktop/test.txt"
end run
```

But when I tried to use `open`

```
open -a test.app --args arg1
```

I get the error

```
Can’t make quoted form of item 1 into type Unicode text. (-1700)
```

I have tried various methods such as `quoted form of` or `as text` but it does not work. I know I can use `osascript` for this but I want to use `open` to change icon/text when I use it with `with administrator privileges`, which doesn't work with `osascript`.

I have also tried changing my script to

```
on run argv
    do shell script "echo " & argv & " >> ~/Desktop/test.txt"
end run
```

and it runs successfully but in the `test.txt`, it prints `current application` instead of the argument that I passed in.

I am testing on Big Sur/Monterey if that matters.

Comment: That isn’t going to work.  The `open` command opens _files_ or _folders_, with the `-a` option specifying the application to use.  An application can accept files - what are you trying to do?

Comment: @red_menace: `open` is also used to launch applications, as OP is doing here. OP’s problem is that AppleScript applets do not pass shell arguments to the script. (They may be confusing `open`’s behavior with `osascript`’s, as the latter can pass shell arguments to the script’s run handler.) If the arguments being passed are file/folder paths, define an `open` handler to receive those as a list of aliases, and use `open -a test.app file1 file2 …`. If the arguments are arbitrary strings, use `NSProcessInfo` via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge to get argv.

Comment: BTW, OP’s code examples should be using `quoted form of (item 1 of argv)` to ensure arbitrary strings are correctly escaped before glomming them into a shell script and eval-ing it via `do shell script`. Forgetting to sanitize one’s inputs is how code injection attacks and other Very Bad Stuff happens.